# How do you upload workers for IronWorker in a Rakefile?

Tags: ruby, ironworker

I know you can use the IronWorker CLI tool to do it from the command line, but I'd like to use a Rakefile to keep it more organized and to load my configuration from a config file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that loads a local config.yml file and with `rake workers:upload` you can upload all your workers:

```
require 'uber_config'
require 'iron_worker_ng'

@config = UberConfig.load
p @config

namespace :workers do
  task :upload_email do
    client = IronWorkerNG::Client.new(@config['iron'])
    # Upload the code
    code = IronWorkerNG::Code::Base.new('workers/email_worker')
    client.codes.create(code)
  end
  task :upload_lead do
    client = IronWorkerNG::Client.new(@config['iron'])
    # Upload the code
    code = IronWorkerNG::Code::Base.new('workers/lead_worker')
    client.codes.create(code)
  end
  task :upload do
    Rake::Task["workers:upload_email"].invoke
    Rake::Task["workers:upload_lead"].invoke
  end

end
```